# Apache poi not finding a hidden sheet

Tags: java, apache, excel, apache-poi

I am trying an example to learn the Apache POI library. In the example I am using a Test.xls excel sheet which has the 3rd sheet as hidden. 
So I am assuming that when I use "workbook.getNumberOfSheets()" the result will be including the hidden sheet, which in my case should be 3. 
But, I keep getting 2 as the result. I want to know how can I find the actual number of sheets incase there is/are hidden sheet in the excel. 
Since in the actual use case I will not know the excel before hand, I would like to know the total number of sheets.

Any help is appreciated and thank you in advance.

Comment: That's odd. I just hid a sheet and tested, and getNumberOfSheets() returned the total number, including the hidden one. Maybe you could post a really simple class here as an example.

Comment: @DariusX. You are right. So apparently, if I open the Test.xls in eclipse itself which launches excel within eclipse, any changes I do to the document do not get reflected on the physical file and hence my hidden sheet. Cos opening the file from file system does not reflect any of my changes. Interesting !!